# What are some methods to declare a reference in C++ other than type &var=var?

Tags: c++, reference

eg:

```
//The standard method
int x=10;
int &y=x;
```

I tried

```
int &y;
y=x;
```

It didn't work, I am looking for another way to run it.

Comment: A reference **must** be initialized (for other types it's highly recommended).

Comment: @Deadman Maybe you tell us what you want to archive.

Comment: Well, `int &y{x}; int &y(x); std::add_lvalue_reference_t<int> y = x;`. What do you *really* want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 types of reference:

rvalue - refer to persistent objects whose value you want to change
lvalue - refer to temporary objects whose value you want to change

lvalue Example:

```
int num = 1;
int& r1 {num};
int& r2; // error: need initialization
int& r2 = num;
int* p = &num;
int& r3 = *p;
```

rvalue Example:

```
int&& rr1{ int() }; // temporary
int&& rr2{ 2 }; // temporary
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a reference without initialising it. Maybe what you want is a pointer.